# Change the style of Kohaha forms

Tags: css, forms, kohana, kohana-3

How do you add styling to Kohana 3 forms.

```
<?= Form::input('new_tag', '',  'style="height:1000px;"');?>
```

This doesn't seem to work. It complains that it needs the third parameter as an array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [the docs for the Form creation method](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Form)

It does indeed want an array at the end.

```
<?= Form::input('new_tag', '',  array('style' => 'height:1000px'));?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to use the following for it to function properly.
<?= Form::input('new_tag', '',  array('style' => 'height:1000px'));?>

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS. Styling does not belong here.